# How to run Sidekiq on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, sidekiq

Today im trying to setup my windows 10 machine with all my Rails environment. While trying to run the `bundle exec sidekiq` command to boot up [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mihaifm/sidekiq-windows) i get the following error:

[image]

It seems that 'daemon() function is not implemented on this machine'. My first guess is that a process in windows does not run as daemon but does as a service?

Environment:

- Windows 10
- Ruby 2.3.0 x64
- Devkit

Tried also dropping the -d option but i get the same error.

Comment: Mike Perham [never promised to support Windows](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/205#issuecomment-5810414), and AFAIK, it’s just not supported by Sidekiq.

Comment: In the same threat some pleople got it working years ago, but i'm not sure how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't daemonize on Windows.  Daemonizing is a legacy option for older Unix systems that only support init.d, no modern systems recommend using it anymore.